# Simple way to add dropdown arrows to a dropdown containing menu?

Tags: navigation

I have a menu (Main menu). It's a superfish based menu that contains simple dropdown appearances. This menu doesn't have any Superfish style attached to it. It just uses the JQuery of this library and that's it; because of this reason I now need to attach arrows to these specific menu links that contain dropdows... Is there any simple module for this purpose and would you even recommend a modular solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use the settings of the Drupal [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) menu itself. There is an option to use "Auto-arrows".

They can be further themed via CSS.

Superfish settings (in configure superfish block)
[image]

This is your site html source. That auto arrow element is there, but because it uses a white background-image you will not see it, so style it like you need it.

[image]

Comment: Before I asked the question I've looked for such thing but didn't find it... I guess I missed it... Could you just indicate where is it exactly?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: Oh... It doesn't work when there is no style... (i.e when style is set to "none")... any alternative to these specific cases when you would prefer to build the style customally?

Comment: As for my side it does also work when there is no style set. You will get <span class="sf-sub-indicator"> ...</span> and can style it like you want to.

Comment: Where should I see the class you mention? At what file?

Comment: Check the html of the superfish menu on your site, there you should see this.

Comment: I swear I haven't seen such athing anywhere relevant...

Not at DOM, not at the Superfish UI. Maybe you mean to a specific TPL? Maybe it's even a bug?

I would have posted Dom syntax\screenshots here but I can't because it's a comment.

Comment: Hm, do you use a superfish block provided by drupal superfish module or how did you implement your superfish menu?

Comment: Indeed I use such block and my menu's machine-name is #superfish-1.

Comment: Can you leave a link to your site?

Comment: beniaharon.co.il

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21462/discussion-between-stefan-korn-and-ben).

Comment: Anyways, it didn't work for me... :| What JQuery update ver you use?